# Assign value to member variable failed, StackOverflowException occured

Tags: c#, ado.net

I want to assign a List to a member variable (the variable is a List), but I always get error message: `System.StackOverflowException` was unhandled, I don't know why, please see my code below:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public int DeptID { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int DeptID { get; set; }
    public string DeptName { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees
    {
        set { Employees = value; }
        //get { return EmployeeDataAccessLayer.getEmployeesByDeptID(DeptID); }
        get { return Employees; }
    }
}
public class EmployeeDataAccessLayer
{
    public static List<Employee> getEmployeesByDeptID(int deptID)
    {
        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string sqlStr = "select * from tblemployee where deptid = :deptid order by employeeid asc";
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
        using (OracleConnection ocon = new OracleConnection(conStr))
        {
            OracleCommand ocmd = new OracleCommand(sqlStr, ocon);
            ocmd.Parameters.Add(":deptid", deptID);
            ocmd.Connection.Open();
            OracleDataReader rdr = ocmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["EMPLOYEEID"]);
                employee.EmployeeName = rdr["NAME"].ToString();
                employee.DeptID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["DEPTID"]);
                employees.Add(employee);
            }
        }
        return employees;
    }
}

public class DepartmentDataAccessLayer
{

    public static List<Department> getAllDepartments()
    {
        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string sqlStr = "select * from tbldepartment order by departmentid asc";
        List<Department> depts = new List<Department>();

        using (OracleConnection ocon = new OracleConnection(conStr))
        {
            OracleCommand ocmd = new OracleCommand(sqlStr, ocon);
            ocmd.Connection.Open();
            OracleDataReader rdr = ocmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Department dept = new Department();
                dept.DeptID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["DEPARTMENTID"]);
                dept.DeptName = rdr["NAME"].ToString();
                dept.Employees = EmployeeDataAccessLayer.getEmployeesByDeptID(dept.DeptID);
                depts.Add(dept);
            }
        }

        return depts;
    }
}
```

so, I debug it and found the exception occured at:

```
set { Employees = value;}
```

see below screenshot:

[image]

I really don't know why, can you tell me the reason or give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're setting `Employees` to `value` which is setting `Employees` to `value` which is setting `Employees` to `value` which is setting.......etc etc until the stack overflows.

Because you're not using a private variable to hold employees, you can just use an auto-getter and -setter to set the value to itself, like your other properties:

```
public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

Otherwise, setup a private variable to hold the list of employees. This can be use

```
private List<Employee> _employees;
public List<Employee> Employees
{
    set { _employees = value; }
    get { return _employees; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, when you assign something to the `Employees` it's setter will trigger it again assigns to the same variable so the same process will continues and it's leads to a infinity assignments, that's why you are getting that Exception. to overcome this Change the property definition like this:

```
private List<Employee> _Employees
public List<Employee> Employees
{
    set { _Employees = value; }      
    get { return _Employees; }
}
```

or like this:

```
public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting a value in C# with get and set, all you'll need to do is

```
public List<Employee> Employees{get; set;}
```

With an empty get and set block, the value will be assigned automatically. In your code, you're essentially calling the set function for your variable over and over again until a StackOverflow exception occurs

More information on properties [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx#Anchor_5)